# Opening a pre-existing excel file

Tags: c#, excel, automation, excel-interop

I am trying to open a pre-existing excel file from a directory on my computer.  However, I am getting a COMexception when my code gets to the Workbooks.Open method.  I'm am unsure what I'm dong wrong.  Any help is appreciated.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Xml;

namespace Excel_Create
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            string mySheet = @"‪‪‪‪C:\Users\Danny\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MWS\MWS\bin\Debug\csharp-Excel.xls";
              Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
              xlApp.Visible = true;


              if (xlApp == null)
              {
                  MessageBox.Show("Excel is not properly installed!!");
                  return;
              }



         Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(mySheet,
          0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
          true, false, 0, true, false, false              );

        }
    }
}
```

Here is what the exception says: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Excel_Create.exe

Additional information: '‪‪‪‪C:\Users\Danny\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MWS\MWS\bin\Debug\csharp-Excel.xls' could not be found. Check the spelling of the file name, and verify that the file location is correct.

Comment: If the file is there, is it open in another application (e.g. Excel)?

Comment: Yep it's there.  It's a Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet (.xls)  saved in : C:\Users\Danny\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MWS\MWS\bin\Debug\csharp-Excel.xls

Copy/paste from properties view of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution that worked for me :

```
     var mySheet = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Sample.xlsx");
          Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
          xlApp.Visible = true;


          if (xlApp == null)
          {
              MessageBox.Show("Excel is not properly installed!!");
              return;
          }

          try
          {
              Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(mySheet);

          }
          catch(Exception ex)
          {
              xlApp.Quit();

          }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're having problems with the spaces in your file path.

Try this, instead:

```
string mySheet = @"""C:\Users\Danny\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MWS\MWS\bin\Debug\csharp-Excel.xls""";
```

Comment: Nope didn't work copy and pasted your code over mine and ran - still the same error

Comment: @DanielTaki are you sure about the filename extension?  Newer versions of Excel use `.xlsx` instead of `.xls`.  Are you sure that it's `.xls`?

Comment: No I'm not sure the excel is from Microsoft office 2010.  Should I try and save the file as a .xlsx then and try to run program again?

Comment: I don't know if this is pertinent information but I may have a cracked copy excel

Answer (score 0):

you may try this ......

```
Excel.Application excelApp = 
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
```